# Node and NVM install broken on Ubuntu 14. Any ideas what I should do?

Tags: node.js, express, nvm

```
which node
```

returns

> /usr/sbin/node

```
which nvm
```

returns nothing

nvm ls returns nothing

express no longer works

If I try `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.11.1/install.sh | bash`

It says

> nvm is already installed in /home/adam/.nvm, trying to update
>   => HEAD is now at 7a423b7... v0.11.1
>   error: branch 'master' not found.

and it is true that .nvm is located there.

Any idea what I should do to either uninstall everything and reinstall it or fix my install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `apt-get install nodejs` installs node as "nodejs" on your path.  Grunt, express, etc. all expect node to be `node` on your path.  The reason for this is there was a  package named node already in the Ubuntu apt repository before node.js came into existence, so node.js couldn't claim "node".  The simplest solution is to do `which nodejs` then create a symlink targeting that file, name it node, and put that on your path (you can just put it in the same directory).

For you I recommend uninstalling everything first (`apt-get remove`).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by deleting everything (purge Ubuntu packages and delete everything created by node and npm in /usr/*) and compiling the node package from their website.

I copied the commands from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-upstream-version-of-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04 instead of linking, in case the site goes offline:

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install
curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
node -v
```

The unofficial install scripts are buggy and it's about time they make an official repository or pre-compile some .deb files to make the installation easier. Hope this helps.

Comment: I fixed it by deleting .nvm and reinstalling using curl.  It still didn't work after that, but once I ran the source line, it worked again.  Makes me think maybe $PATH just got messed up somehow.  How did you purge evergting created by node and npm? Just with rm -rf?

Comment: Purge with "apt-get purge nodejs" and the manually installed files in /usr with sudo rm -r (absolute path names for safety).